# Does gdalinfo report tifftag_datetime capture date?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, gdalinfo

Is gdalinfo meant to report the date a geotiff was captured? When I run it in qgis the tifftag_datetime seems to report the date it was saved to disk, rather that capture/creation date.

Is there a way I can see the capture date?

Comment: Datetime is a baseline tiff tag http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/datetime.html. Aerial images etc. are not really snapshots from the air but produced by computers. Image producers do not use that field for acquisition time. Metadata is held in externals documents.